# Is there an advantage/disadvantage to open a different tcp port for every client?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server

I build a middle ware server.
I have 5(or 6) clients(different computer/IP address), and every client can have up to 6 connection -> max 36 connection to the server.

It is better to use only 1 port for all (e.g. 9000) or one different port for every client(e.g. 9000-9005) ?

I write me a simple test server(see code).
It worked like expected but maybe there is some room for optimization.

Thanks

My TCP server

```
public class TCPServerMulti : IDisposable
    { 
    private static TcpListener _tcpListener;
    private string _ipAdress = "";
    private int _port = 9050;
    private readonly Thread _listener;
    private readonly bool _running;

    private int cc = 0; //Test Counter

    public string IPAdress
    {
        get { return _ipAdress; }
        set { _ipAdress = value; }
    }

    public TCPServerMulti(int port)
    {
        if(port>0)
            _port = port;

        _running = true;
        string sHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPAdress = "";
        //Only use the first address -> need to change
        IPAddress[] localAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(sHostName);
        foreach (IPAddress ipAddress in localAddress)
        {
            if (ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                _tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, _port);
                IPAdress = ipAddress.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (IPAdress == "")
        {
            Console.Writeline("TCP Error");
            return;
        }
        _tcpListener.Start();
        _listener = new Thread(Listen) { IsBackground = true };
        _listener.Start();
    }
    public TCPServerMulti():this(-1)
    {}
    //listening for clients
    public void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            while(_running)
            {
                cc++;
                //create a own client object for every connection
                TCPClientData cd = new TCPClientData(this, ""+cc, _tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient());
                cd.StartClient();
                if (ClientConnected != null) ClientConnected("Connected: " + cc);
            }
            _tcpListener.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _listener.Abort();
        _tcpListener.Stop();
    }
    //Handle for Mainthread
    internal void ReceiveClient(TCPClientData sender, string msg)
    {
        if (ReceiveMsg != null)
            ReceiveMsg(sender, msg);
    }

    public delegate void ReceiveEventHandler(TCPClientData sender, string msg);
    public event ReceiveEventHandler ReceiveMsg;

    public delegate void ConnectedEventHandler(string msg);
    public event ConnectedEventHandler ClientConnected;
}
```

Clientdata object

```
public class TCPClientData : IDisposable
{
    private TCPServerMulti _master;
    private byte[] _data;
    private NetworkStream _networkStream;
    private int _received;
    private TcpClient _tcpClient;

    private Thread _worker;
    private bool _wrunning;

    private string _id;
    public TCPClientData(TCPServerMulti master,string id,TcpClient client)
    {
        _data = new byte[1024];
        _master = master;
        _id = id;
        _tcpClient = client;
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }

    private string ByteArrayToString(byte[] arr)
    {
        UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
        return enc.GetString(arr);
    }

    private byte[] StringToByteArray(string data)
    {
        UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
        return enc.GetBytes(data);
    }
    // Reading Data
    private void Worker()
    {
        try
        {
            while (_wrunning)
            {

                if (_networkStream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    _received = _networkStream.Read(_data, 0, _data.Length);

                    string s = ByteArrayToString(_data);
                    _master.ReceiveClient(this, s.Substring(0, _received));
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
            }
            _networkStream.Close();
            _tcpClient.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _worker.Abort();
        _networkStream.Close();
        _tcpClient.Close();
    }

    public void StartClient()
    {
        _networkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
        _networkStream.ReadTimeout = 200;
        _wrunning = true;
        _worker = new Thread(Worker) { IsBackground = true };
        _worker.Start();
    }
    public void StopClient()
    {
        _wrunning = false;
        Thread.Sleep(700);
    }
    //Sending Data
    public void WriteData(string msg)
    {
        byte[] b = StringToByteArray(msg);
        _networkStream.Write(b,0,b.Length);
        _networkStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

Main Thread

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create Server
        TCPServerPlugin.TCPServerMulti server=new TCPServerMulti(12345);
        server.ClientConnected += Server_ClientConnected;
        server.ReceiveMsg += Server_ReceiveMsg;
        while (true)
        {

        }
    }
    //Callbacks
    private static void Server_ClientConnected(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    private static void Server_ReceiveMsg(TCPClientData sender, string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Sender: {0} -> MSG:{1}",sender.ID,msg));
        if (msg == "!!X")
        {
            sender.Dispose();
            sender = null;
        }
        else if(msg=="DATE")
            sender.WriteData(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        else if(msg=="TIME")
            sender.WriteData(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
    }
```

Comment: tcp allows a server to open one port which will transfer to an ephemeral.  that way the clients don't have to organize.

Comment: A TCP connection is identified with the couple IP/Port. Since your clients have different IP addresses, you don't need to use different ports, it is even better to use the same port for the same service for simplicity in your code.